# What type of encryption used bcrypt-ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-2.0

I have a problem accessing from an android application and need to know what type of encryption used `bcrypt-ruby` gem in the web part of the application. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of [bcrypt_ruby](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby), looks like it uses blowfish.